# Stupid factorial question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

If i have $(3(n+1))!$ can I say:

$(3(n+1))! = 3(n+1) \times (3n)!$

but if I expand by first multiplying the expression in the parenthesis;

$(3(n+1))! = (3n+3) \times (3n+2) \times (3n+1) \times (3n)!$

Which one is it? I think the second one.

Comment: Yes, the second one.

Comment: Yes. The second one is correct.

Comment: Might be better to write $3(n+1)=3n+3$, from which $(3n+3)!=(3n+3) \times (3n+3-1) \times (3n+3-2)\ldots$ so your reasoning in your second example is correct.

Comment: That's not a stupid question.

Comment: @GFauxPas No one said it was

Comment: @JMoravitz read the title to the question.

Answer (score 2):

$$(3(n+1))! = 3(n+1) \times (3(n+1)-1)! = 3(n+1) \times (3n +2)!$$
Repeating the above, you get the second answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your confusion become from the recursive definition of factorial as:
$$
0!=1 \, \quad (s(n))!=s(n) \cdot n!
$$
where $s(n)=n+1$ is the successor of $n$.

Note that $3(n+1) $ is not the successor of $3n$ but of $3n+2$.

So you have the correct result:
$$
(3(n+1))! =3(n+1)\cdot (3n+2)!
$$

The successor of $3n$ is $3n+1$.